# Data is lost after rotation on jetpack compose with navigation

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation

when I rotate my app in jetpack compose (with navigation), all data is reset

after each rotation, it goes in the onCreate of the activity and create again the NavHost and the ViewModel. I thought it would be handled with the app state

[image: example]

the starting activity :

```
class NavActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            MyAppTheme() {
                MyAppApp()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the app which contains the NavHost :

```
@Composable
fun MyAppApp(
    appState:  MyAppAppState = rememberAppState()
) {
        NavHost(
            navController = appState.navController,
            startDestination = Screen.ProductAddPath.route
            )
        {
            composable(Screen.ProductAddPath.route) {
                ProductEditView(
                    vm = ProductEditViewModel (appState.context)
                )
            }
        }
}
```

the viewmodel :

```
class ProductEditViewModel(context: Context) : ViewModel() {

    private val _productName = MutableStateFlow("qsd")
    val productName = _productName.asStateFlow()
    
    fun onProductNameChange(it: String) {
        _productName.value = it
    }


}
```

My View :

```
@Composable
fun ProductEditView(vm: ProductEditViewModel) {
    Surface( color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
        val message by vm.productName.collectAsState()
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = message,
                onValueChange = { vm.onProductNameChange(it) },
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I put a working project on github

https://github.com/psohm/data-lost-rotation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your `ProductEditViewModel` is recreated every time that the **context** from `MyAppAppState` changes, consequently, all data is reset. You can do a very simple test by adding an `init` block to the view model with a `println`, and you will notice that when you rotate the screen, or even change the device's theme, the contents of the `init` block will be fired again. 
By removing the `Context` parameter from the `ProductEditViewModel` this "problem" will no longer happen.

Note that it is bad practice to pass a `Context` to a `ViewModel`, when you adopt this kind of approach you will end up falling into two situations. 
The first is to break the ViewModel lifecycle and make it useless in relation to what it purports to be (hold the data independent of the lifecycle of activities/fragments/composables). 
The second is to cause memory leaks and most likely ANR as a result.

You can take a look [**here**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) and [**here**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodels-source-of-truth) to get a general idea of the ViewModel's purpose, how its lifecycle works and some practical examples of use.

**Edit:** 
The way the ViewModel instance is created is also important. And that was the detail that made you lose the ViewModel data at the beginning.

Let's imagine the following ViewModel:

```kotlin
class MyViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    init {
        println("MyViewModel created")
    }
}
```

If we instantiate it like this:

```kotlin
MyComposableFuncion(
    viewModel: MyViewModel = MyViewModel()
)
```

We are not dealing with an instance that will persist. That's because we just called a MyViewModel instance and this action will be repeated when the screen is rotated, generating a new instance of this ViewModel with all the default data.

If we do it like this:

```kotlin
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel

MyComposableFuncion(
    viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()
)
```

Now we use the `viewModel()` function instead of passing the `MyViewModel()`. The `viewModel()` deal behind the scenes with the persistence of the ViewModel instance, even if the screen is rotated.

If the ViewModel has parameters, it is necessary to create a `ViewModelProvider.Factory` that provides the necessary parameters, and then pass this factory in the viewModel() function. 
The [tutorial](https://www.answertopia.com/jetpack-compose/a-jetpack-compose-room-database-and-repository-tutorial/) that was mentioned in the comments has all this information explained as well:

> Previously we have used the viewModel() function to create view models. Unfortunately, the viewModel() function will not allow us to simply pass through the Application reference as an argument when we call it. Instead, we need to pass the function a custom ViewModelProvider Factory class designed to accept an Application reference and return an initialized MainViewModel instance.

My suggestion would be to use some library to inject dependencies, like [Hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android). But I believe that if you are just starting to learn, the most important thing is to follow the tutorial you chose until the end, so you don't mix things up and get complicated.

Comment: tks for your answer. i followed your solution and removed context, but the rotation problem remains. init is fired twice. btw i added context to add rooms support https://www.answertopia.com/jetpack-compose/a-jetpack-compose-room-database-and-repository-tutorial/ what is the good practice ?

Comment: I ended up forgetting to detail another important point, which is basically how you call your `ViewModel`. This problem is inside the composable `MyAppApp`, when calling the `ProductEditView` you keep creating a new `ProductEditViewModel()`. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#implement-viewmodel) suggests that you instantiate a ViewModel with the `viewModel()` function, from `androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel` (you must add the dependency `'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.5.1'` for that)

Comment: About the tutorial you mentioned, the `Application` was used as a parameter in the ViewModel. The `Context` and `Application` are not the same thing, while the context will change depending on certain scenarios in your app, the application in turn will remain the same until the app is closed. However, if you have a view model with parameters, you will have to create a custom `ViewModelProvider` and pass to the `viewModel()` function I mentioned above.

Comment: tks again,I added the dependancy but I didn't catch what is the relevant fix.  can you be more explicit ? (and I got it for the Applications tks)

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide more information.

Comment: that was the way. tks a lot